# Naming: Microservice that provides ad-hoc executable tasks to solve productive issues

Tags: microservices, naming

hope this naming-question is not too subjective or suggestive but we are just building a microservice that only provides webservice/JMX-executable minimal jobs/tasks/runnables/callables/scripts that are meant to fix specific things on production, e.g. resetting status, deleting entities, regenerate documents: fixing various things.

we are also using it for one-time setup-foobar that needs to get manually triggered like: migrate this data or generate those messages.

we want it to be a separately deployable artifact/microservice to deploy such scripts as fast as possible.

now, we are looking for a name that fits the thing, the nom de guerre is "production support", isnt there anything more concise and to the point?

*fixer* ? that wouldn't transport the fact it can also be non-fixing migration/generating stuff.

any naming advice appreciated :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this qualifies as "opinion-based" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI we went with "sup" for production-support-tasks.

however we are actually phasing out this concept alltogether because it collects dependencies from all domains for which it provides "production support" services.